# How can I implement a scroll bar that adapts to zoom on a Chart.js chart?

Tags: charts, chart.js, scrollbar

I'm trying to implement a scroll bar, which adapts to zoom, on a chart made with chart.js.
I've found several posts that allow me to implement the scroll bar. So I made a code pen to try it out.

[Here's the result.](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/rNqEQpe)

However, I realized that a problem persists.
Whenever I zoom in, the scroll bar doesn't adapt to keep covering the whole chart. In other words, after i zoom in, I can no longer scroll over the entire chart.
I managed to achieve the desired result with FusionCharts, but not with Chart.js.
The "problem" is that way i made this is intrinsic to FusionCharts and there is no code to take inspiration from to implement it with chart.js.

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
var myChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: "zoomline",
    renderAt: "chart-container",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    dataFormat: "json",
    dataSource
  }).render();
});
```

[Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/XWxLyVK)

So I was wondering if anyone has managed to implement such a scroll bar, and if so, how did you proceed?

Comment: You can use fusioncharts to meet this requirement, don't think chartjs support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot about this question...

In the end, I managed to implement the scrollbar with a custom inline plugin.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  isDragging,
  rectPosition = null;

 function generateData(number){
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < number ; i++){
      data.push(Math.random()*10);
    }
    return data;
  }

function generateLabels(number){
  let labels = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < number ; i++){
    labels.push(i);
  }
  return labels;
}

function generateDatasets(nbrDatasets, nbrData) {
  var datasets = [];
  for(let i = 0 ; i < nbrDatasets ; i++ ){
    datasets.push({data: generateData(nbrData), pointRadius: 0, pointHoverRadius: 7, label: `Dataset ${i}`});
  }
  return datasets;
}

var cfg = {
  type: 'line',
  data:{
    labels: generateLabels(100),
    datasets: generateDatasets(2, 100),
  },
  options:{
    animations: false,
    responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    normalized: true,
    layout: {
                padding: {
                bottom: 40,
            },
        },
    interaction:{
            mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: false,
          axis: 'x'
        },
    plugins:{
      zoom:{
        zoom:{
          drag:{
            modifierKey: 'shift',
            enabled:true,
          },
          mode: 'x',
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins:[{
                id: "zoomRangeSlider",
                afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, plugins) {
                    var chartMin = chart.data.labels[0],
                        chartMax = chart.data.labels[chart.data.labels.length - 1],
                        currentZoom = chart.options.scales.x.max - chart.options.scales.x.min,
                        minMaxDiff = chartMax - chartMin,
                        posX;
                    const {
                        ctx,
                        chartArea: {
                            left,
                            top,
                            bottom,
                            right,
                            width
                        },
                    } = chart;
                    var rectWidth = (currentZoom / minMaxDiff) * width;

                    if(rectWidth < 7) {
                        rectWidth = 7;
                    }

                    posX = (chart.options.scales.x.min - chartMin) / minMaxDiff;
                    rectPosition = (posX * (width)) + (rectWidth / 2) + left;

                    if (rectPosition < left + rectWidth / 2) {
                        rectPosition = left + rectWidth / 2
                    }

                    // Scrollbar background
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f0f0f0";
                    ctx.rect(left, bottom + 40, width, 15);
                    ctx.fill();

                    // Scrollbar
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#cdcdcd";
                    ctx.rect(rectPosition - (rectWidth / 2), bottom + 40, rectWidth, 13);
                    ctx.fill();
                },

                afterEvent(chart, args, plugins) {
                    var chartMin = chart.data.labels[0],
                        chartMax = chart.data.labels[chart.data.labels.length - 1],
                        currentZoom = chart.options.scales.x.max - chart.options.scales.x.min,
                        step = chart.data.labels[1] - chart.data.labels[0],
                        minMaxDiff = chartMax - chartMin;
                    const {
                        ctx,
                        canvas,
                        chartArea: {
                            left,
                            top,
                            bottom,
                            right,
                            width
                        },
                    } = chart;

                    if (args.event.type === "mousemove" && isDragging === true && args.event.y > 1.05 * bottom) {

                        // Check where the mouse is
                        var xPosition = parseFloat(((args.event.x-left) / (right-left)).toFixed(2));
                        xPosition = xPosition > 1 ? 1 : xPosition < 0 ? 0 : xPosition;
                        var min = chartMin + (xPosition * minMaxDiff) - (0.5 * currentZoom) - (chartMin + (xPosition * minMaxDiff) - (0.5 * currentZoom)) % step,
                            max = min + currentZoom;

                        if (max >= chartMax) {
                            max = chartMax;
                            min = max - currentZoom;
                        } else if (min < chartMin) {
                            min = chartMin;
                            max = min + currentZoom;
                        }

                        chart.options.scales.x.min = min;
                        chart.options.scales.x.max = max;
                        args.changed = true;

                        // Synchronize the grid and the chart
                        chart.update('none');
                    }
                },
            }]
};

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);

canvas.onmousedown = function(){
    isDragging = true;
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(){
    isDragging = false;
};

function zoomout(){
  myChart.options.scales.x.min = undefined;
  myChart.options.scales.x.max = undefined;
  myChart.update('none');
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js "></script>

<div class="container">
  <button onclick="zoomout()">Zoom out</button>
  <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
</div>
```